# How to get counts using the `IN` operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use the `IN` operator to get the count of certain fields  in the table.

This is my query:

```
SELECT order_id, COUNT(*)
FROM remake_error_type
WHERE order_id IN (1, 2, 100)
GROUP BY order_id;
```

My current output:

```
| order_id | COUNT(*) |
+----------+----------+
|    1     |    8     |
|    2     |    8     |
```

My expected output:

```
| order_id | COUNT(*) |
+----------+----------+
|    1     |    8     |
|    2     |    8     |
|    100   |    0     |
```

Comment: The numbers i have added in operator i.e (1,2,100) is just for example, it is dynamic i.e it can be more than 3 numbers

Comment: Is `order_id ` a foreign key?

Comment: Yes order_id is foreign key

Answer (score 2):

You can write your query this way:

```
SELECT t.id, COUNT(remake_error_type.order_id)
FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 100) as t
  LEFT JOIN remake_error_type
  ON t.id = remake_error_type.order_id
GROUP BY
  t.id
```

a `LEFT JOIN` will return all rows from the subquery on the left, and the `COUNT(remake_error_type.order_id)` will count all values where the join succeeds.

Comment: The numbers i have added in operator i.e (1,2,100) is just for example, it is dynamic i.e it can be more than 3 numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temporary table, insert as many `order_ids` as required, and perform the `left join` to `remake_error_type`. At a small number of orders the other answers are sufficient, but if you were doing this for a lot of orders, `UNION ALL` and sub-queries are inefficient, both to type it up and to execute on the server.

Additionally, this is a very dynamic approach, because you can control easily the values in your temp table by modifying the insert statement.

However, this will only work if the database user has sufficient privileges: at least select, create temporary and drop table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTempOrders;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTempOrders (order_id INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(order_id));
INSERT INTO myTempOrders (order_id) VALUES (1), (2), (100);

SELECT temp.order_id, count(*)

FROM myTempOrders temp
LEFT JOIN remake_error_type ON temp.order_id = remake_error_type.order_id
GROUP BY 1
```

If the `order_id` values exist in some table, then it is possible to extract the desired result without creating a temporary table and inserting values into it.

To qualify, the table must

- have an auto increment primary key with # rows greater than the maximum sought `order_id` value
- have a starting increment value less than the minimum sought `order_id` value
- have no missing values in the primary key (i.e. no records have been deleted)

if a qualified table exists, then you can run the following query, where you have to replace `surrogate` with the `qualified table name` and surrogate_id with the `auto-incrementing primary key` of the `qualified table name`

```
SELECT surrogate.surrogate_id, count(*)

FROM my_qualified_table surrogate
LEFT JOIN remake_error_type ON surrogate.surrogate_id = remake_error_type.order_id
WHERE surrogate.surrogate_id IN (1, 2, 100)
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, i don't have enough privileges to create temp table and  delete it. All i can do is only run a select query.

Comment: do these `order_id` values exist in some other table? Then you can use my edited answer.

Comment: No order_id doesn't exits in other table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a union for this. No, this does not use the `IN` operator, but it is an alternative that will give you your expected results. One option is to hardcode the order_id and use conditional aggregation to get the `SUM()` of rows with that id:

```
SELECT 1 AS order_id, SUM(order_id = 1) AS numOrders FROM myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS order_id, SUM(order_id = 2) AS numOrders FROM myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 100 AS order_id, SUM(order_id = 100) AS numOrders FROM myTable;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6db70/1) example.

Comment: The numbers i have added in operator i.e (1,2,100) is just for example, it is dynamic i.e it can be more than 3 numbers

Comment: So what are you passing into the query? an array?

Comment: Not array, i will be passing more than 100 numbers, also i do not have permission to create or delete temp table.